# Take out all occurences of element in list

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I have this code:

```
(define remove
  (λ (x y)
    (cond 
          ((null? y) '())
          ((eq? x (car y)) (delete x (cdr y)))
          (else (cons (car y) (delete x (cdr y))))
)))

Input: (remove 'c '(w((x)(c q)(((o))))w))
```

This will not go inside the inner parenthesis. If I try to remove 'w', it will remove all occurrences of it because they are outside of the parenthesis. So, I can't take out anything from the inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a bit more elaborate, you'll have to use the template for traversing a list of lists. Also, is better to use `equal?` instead of `eq?`, consult the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html) to understand the differences. A possible implementation follows, I took the liberty of renaming the parameters to something more meaningful:

```
(define remove
  (λ (ele lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) '())           ; if the list is empty then we're done
      ((not (pair? (car lst)))    ; if the first element is an atom
       (if (equal? (car lst) ele) ; check if it's the one we're looking for
           (remove ele (cdr lst)) ; if so we skip over it, eliminating it
           (cons (car lst) (remove ele (cdr lst))))) ; otherwise we add it
      (else (cons (remove ele (car lst))      ; else advance recursion
                  (remove ele (cdr lst))))))) ; over both `car` and `cdr`
```

Now it works as expected:

```
(remove 'c '(w ((x) (c q) (((o)))) w))
=> '(w ((x) (q) (((o)))) w)
```

Comment: Thanks! It makes a lot more sense now.